# How can I fetch the number of comments from db?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the number of comments from my database (like in facebook: not the comments but the total number of comments per article [or in my case per "listing"]).

How can I get the number of comments?

Comment: im a beginner... how do i print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select the `count(*)` of your database, which will give you the count of rows you need.

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM `comment_table` GROUP BY `listing_id`;
```

Comment: he wants per listing, you need group by

Comment: @Derek Corrected even before you posted this comment :) (Please remove the -1)

Answer (score 2):

```
select listing_id, count(*) 
from table
group by listing_id
```

Comment: im a beginner... how do i print it?